# Mysql architecture best practice: user attributes

Tags: mysql, architecture

I have  a mysql table with my users... each user has various attributes like Verified(yes/no), Member (yes/no) etc.. i dont need to explain more..is a very common case...

i've been alwasy using to build my tables with single rows like this, maybe for lazyness or just because i never built big DB so far...

```
userId | userName | Verified | Member
---------------------------------------
  3213 | Jon      | 1        | 0
```

but i wonder if there is any advantages to build it into separate tables, and create relationships later, like

**User Table**

```
userId | userName | 
-------------------
  3213 | Jon      |
```

**Memberships table**

```
memberId | userId   | Member   |
--------------------------------
  555748 | 3213     | 0        |
```

**Verifications Table**

```
memberId | userId   | Verified   |
----------------------------------
  555748 | 3213     | 1          |
```

what is the real benefit from this second choice?

Comment: You might want to become familiar with [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real advantage here, only disadvantages. There is a 1:1 relationship between the tables, and now you have to join the two tables to get the verification state of a user. Also, there are more possible cases now: a user can be verified (1) unverified (0) or the record might not exist.

You can better put these extra fields in the same table, unless there's a 1 to many relationship. For example, a user can have posts, friends, pictures, which you store in a separate table because you don't know how many you need to save.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the first way, it consumes less space and is propably also faster as long as it is a 1:1 relation.

Answer (score 0):

The point of separation is to allow one to many, many to one, or many to many records. As long as none of your data fields can possibly contain the same information, a flat table is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably simplify it a little. Since there is no value in having a flag which indicates the membership/verification. The table separation does that for you. Also, you do not need have userId in every table. You probably have a UserMember table, which contain both the identity of the user and member. So having the relationship is enough.

Also, if you have a 1:1 relationship you could as well have the flag in the same table. Having a 1:x relationship is more appropriative for normalization.